# ASP.NET Core 2 error 500.19 when hosting on somee.com

Tags: c#, hosting, somee

I have a small project for school, my teacher needs this project to be  hosted on Internet. My project works fine in IIS 10 but when I deployed it on somee.com, `error 500` happened that made me lost one day but cannot fix it. Please help me to solve this . Sorry for my bad English.
Here my error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJm8f.png)

Here my code in `web.config` :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLNHK.png)

Thanks for your help. Please comment if you want to know more details

Comment: Do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665322/how-to-set-web-config-file-to-show-full-error-message) and come back to us with the error message.

Comment: it's still show the same 500 error again :( @John

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40805402/http-error-500-19-when-publish-net-core-project-into-iis) is related.

Comment: Hi there! You should know, that images of code and exceptions are useless. Please, read [this](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and [this](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) and update your question.

Comment: @John my config error is empty and it doesnt show message look like your topic you posted :( i have read alot of topic but cannot fix it

Comment: @vasily.sib i put all my project on somee.com so i cannot open code to paste here. Also this is the first time i post a topic in here so sorry you about that

Comment: @PhátThanhLâm as you put all your project files to somee.com, you can get them from somee.com, right?

Comment: @vasily.sib i dont know how to get them but i still have source code in my pc

Answer (score 0):

You must assign modify permissions to the application pool user on the directory holding the website files, and the permissions must be allowing them to read and write. For some reason. NET Core requires write permissions to run on IIS.

Comment: year look like what you said , i set permissions for asp.net core it works ok in iis but when i deployed on somee.com it's wrong . I read alot of topic and they said error 0x8007000d occurs because web.config wrong in code but i cannot find out :( two days i fight with it

Comment: Have you installed the AspNetCore component for IIS on the server, you will probably have it on IIS 10 on your machine but if the server doesn't include it, then it will not work properly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle

Comment: I have installed .net core hosting bundle + url rewrite module 2 for running on IIS 10