# How to setup a .NET core HTTP Proxy in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core

Need help to configure .NET Core HTTP proxy application on IIS on Windows 10.

I did build an proxy app to help me inject the SOAP headers before passing the request to the Final WS endpoint.

I had build this proxy because the client wont have a capability to send on headers on the request

I am mimicking the code that was shared by Andrea Chiarelli in the following link

[Auth0 .NET Core Proxy](https://auth0.com/blog/building-a-reverse-proxy-in-dot-net-core/)

When I run the application **locally on VS Code Everything works well**

But soon I deployed to IIS server sing VS 2017. I ran into a problem

**Web.Config**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\EMCIProxy.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I am getting a strange response that I cannot access the specific URL resource

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Detailed Error Information:
Module
   IIS Web Core
Notification
   Unknown
Handler
   Not yet determined
Error Code
   0x8007000d
Config Error

Config File
   \?\C:\inetpub\EMXI_Proxy\web.config
Requested URL
   http://localhost:8085/
Physical Path

Logon Method
   Not yet determined
Logon User
   Not yet determined

Config Source:
   -1: 
    0:

I am trying to access the URL http://XYZ123:8085/services/SearchClient which should be routed to 
https://testxyz:7443/EMXI/services"

Just want to mention I exactly have one method *public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)* similar to the one on the example provided in the above URL

Any points of advice/suggestions welcome. I am trying to leave it very generic as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that ASP Windows Hosting Module was not installed on my machine. Just want to point to another stack question, where I found the solution

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40805402/http-error-500-19-when-publish-net-core-project-into-iis)