# Dotnet Core 3.1 HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I was trying to create a simple (default) Web API using **dotnet core 3.1** in Visual Studio 2019 using "ASP.NET Core Web Application".

Once I created the (default) application and **I was able to run it on IIS Express** by pressing F5 in Visual Studio.

Then I want to publish so I went to windows features and turned on IIS then configured it by installing **"WebPlatformInstaller_x64_en-US.msi"** and **"dotnet-hosting-3.1.2-win.exe"** (for dot net core).

Then I ran the following in command prompt:

```
net stop was /y
net start w3svc
```

I did the **publish** using **"Default Web Site/Test"** configuration pointing to host: http://localhost and Self Contain Package with DotNet Core 3.1.

Also created a Application pool with **"No Managed Code"**

[image: Application Pool]

When I went to http://localhost/Test
**I got the following error message:**

[image: Error Message]

Here is my **Web.Config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
  </handlers>
  <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\TestApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 63addee1-2c1f-4679-94f4-df9dc952d8f9-->
```

I'm not sure if this is relevant information, when I did Pass-through Authentication test in IIS I'm getting the following:

[image: Pass-through Authentication Test Results]

I tried so many different ways of publishing and they all at the end getting the above error message. How can we resolve this?

Comment: Have you installed the ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle, and restarted the W3SVC service to refresh the PATH variable?

Comment: I have installed the latest and did the following by running CMD under admin mode:
net stop was /y then
net start w3svc

Comment: Run some basic diagnostics, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: JexusManager is throwing the exact same issue when I try to open the web.config with it.

Comment: It turned out to be our server was not allowed to have IIS turned on. It was configured as a data server. I had to get special permission to run IIS, then everything seems to work fine.

Comment: reinstall asp.net core hosting bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be our server was not allowed to have IIS turned on. **It was configured as a data server**. I had to get special permission to run IIS, then everything seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3):

1. ensure corresponding Application Pool configured with No Managed Code
2. ensure you've installed [.NET Core Hosting Bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle)

Answer (score 0):

IMO, I will say you take a look through this walkthrough:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Try check if Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) is activated on your system (server).

Turn stdoutLogEnabled="true" to get more detailed error from the app in a log file.
Or turn on Developer Error Page in your Startup.cs class.

Comment: I did turn it on but then I realized my error is saying that it's having issues with Web.config. So not sure if it can even read the stdoutLogEnabled="true" configuration.

Comment: Oops, U can try this as a follow up, I know its 2.** solution but it should work for this situation too I guess.

https://bytutorial.com/blogs/asp-net-core/http-error-50019---internal-server-error-when-publishing-aspnet-core-web-api-to-iis-server

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40805402/http-error-500-19-when-publish-net-core-project-into-iis

Answer (score 0):

At My case, I attach .NET Core 3.1 apps on IIS win server 2019

I have installed .net core 3.1 runtime, and Hosting bundle, but something goes wrong

[image: saka_iis]

when I check at local compter  I am missing :

```
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

After I install .net Core Desktop Runtime the error gone.

[image: cmd]

[image: runtime]

Maybe the runtime need another installer..